# Excel Index Match - Only return value if begins with certain letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an index match formula however I need it to only display if the result begins with a certain character.

The formula I currently have is:

```
 =INDEX('1'!E10:E205,MATCH(B36,'1'!G10:G205, 0))
```

However when returning the value (in E10:E205) column I need it only to display if it begins with an 'x'.

I just can't figure out where to go with this so any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: An if() formula around your index would probably help. Does the result need to begin with an 'x' or should it contain an 'x'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
=IF(LEFT(INDEX('1'!E10:E205,MATCH(B36,'1'!G10:G205,0)),1)="x",INDEX('1'!E10:E205,MATCH(B36,'1'!G10:G205,0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX('1'!E10:E205,MATCH(B36,'1'!G10:G205, 0))`

Okay so the row number returned at the moment is when `'1'!G` matches `B36`. You want to add another logical on the row number, offset to the start of the `INDEX` (indexed position). There are a couple of ways to do this:

First you can build a string of the two columns together for `MATCH` to evaluate and use wildcards:

`=INDEX('1'!E10:E205,MATCH("x*"&B36,'1'!E10:E205&'1'!G10:G205, 0))`

The `*` wildcard will allow for any number of any character so you will get what you are looking for.

Another way would be to use `SMALL(IF())` to build an array of index postions and return the nth smallest:

`=INDEX('1'!E10:E205,SMALL(IF(LEFT('1'!E10:E205,1)="x",IF('1'!G10:G205=B36,ROW('1'!G10:G205)-9)),ROW(10:10)))` - This is an array formula; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> While still in the formula bar